# get process info from proc

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I need to make a kernel module to display some basic process information from proc directory. For eg. getting all process IDs in proc and storing them in an array. I checked "proc_fs.h" header file on [this link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h)

but it seems it does not contain any function to get such data. Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

Can anyone provide names of any such header files that can be helpful or links to any such resource.

Comment: Why do you need a kernel module? `/proc` is available from user mode obviously. If you are in a kernel module, then you should probably use the raw information, not parse back stuff from `/proc`.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some basic and detailed information in the proc. You can issue > sudo cat /proc/{file} to output the information for you to grep.

```
/proc/cpuinfo
Information about the processor, such as its type, make, model, and performance.

/proc/[pid]/cmdline
This holds the complete command line for the process, unless the whole process has been swapped out, or unless the process is a zombie. In either of these later cases, there is nothing in this file: i.e. a read on this file will return 0 characters. The command line arguments appear in this file as a set of null-separated strings, with a further null byte after the last string.

/proc/[pid]/cwd
This is a link to the current working directory of the process.

/proc/[pid]/environ
This file contains the environment for the process. The entries are separated by null characters, and there may be a null character at the end.

/proc/[pid]/exe
The exe file is a symbolic link containing the actual path name of the executed command. The exe symbolic link can be dereferenced normally – attempting to open exe will open the executable. You can even type /proc/[pid]/exe to run another copy of the same process as [pid].

/proc/[pid]/fd
This is a subdirectory containing one entry for each file which the process has opened, named by its file descriptor, and which is a symbolic link to the actual file (as the exe entry does). Thus, 0 is standard input, 1 standard output, 2 standard error, etc.

/proc/[pid]/maps
A file containing the currently mapped memory regions and their access permissions.

/proc/[pid]/mem
The mem file provides a means to access the process memory pages, using open, fseek and read commands.

/proc/[pid]/root
This is a link to the root directory which is seen by the process. This root directory is usually “/”, but it can be changed by the chroot command.

/proc/[pid]/stat
This file provides status information about the process. This is used by the Process Show utility. It is defined in fs/proc/array.c source file and may differ from one distribution to another.

/proc/devices
List of device drivers configured into the currently running kernel.

/proc/dma
Shows which DMA channels are being used at the moment.

[root@devops ~]# cat /proc/dma
4: cascade

/proc/filesystems
Filesystems configured into the kernel.

[root@devops ~]# cat /proc/filesystems
nodev sysfs
nodev rootfs
nodev bdev
nodev proc
nodev cgroup
nodev cpuset
nodev tmpfs
nodev devtmpfs
nodev binfmt_misc
nodev debugfs
nodev securityfs
nodev sockfs
nodev usbfs
nodev pipefs
nodev anon_inodefs
nodev inotifyfs
nodev devpts
nodev ramfs
nodev hugetlbfs
iso9660
nodev pstore
nodev mqueue
ext3
nodev xenfs

/proc/interrupts
Shows which interrupts are in use, and how many of each there have been.

/proc/ioports
Which I/O ports are in use at the moment.

[root@devops ~]# cat /proc/ioports
0000-0cf7 : PCI Bus 0000:00
0000-001f : dma1
0020-0021 : pic1
0040-0043 : timer0
0050-0053 : timer1
0060-0060 : keyboard
0064-0064 : keyboard
0070-0071 : rtc0
0080-008f : dma page reg
00a0-00a1 : pic2
00c0-00df : dma2

/proc/kcore
An image of the physical memory of the system. This is exactly the same size as your physical memory, but does not really take up that much memory; it is generated on the fly as programs access it. (Remember: unless you copy it elsewhere, nothing under /proc takes up any disk space at all.)

/proc/kmsg
Messages output by the kernel. These are also routed to syslog.

/proc/ksyms
Symbol table for the kernel.

/proc/loadavg
The `load average’ of the system; three meaningless indicators of how much work the system has to do at the moment.

/proc/meminfo
Information about memory usage, both physical and swap.

[root@devops ~]# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal: 500832 kB
MemFree: 116376 kB
Buffers: 1964 kB
Cached: 38772 kB
SwapCached: 0 kB
Active: 157548 kB
Inactive: 187552 kB
Active(anon): 149852 kB
Inactive(anon): 154960 kB
Active(file): 7696 kB
Inactive(file): 32592 kB
Unevictable: 0 kB
Mlocked: 0 kB
SwapTotal: 0 kB
SwapFree: 0 kB
Dirty: 96 kB
Writeback: 0 kB
AnonPages: 304388 kB
Mapped: 11180 kB
Shmem: 448 kB
Slab: 25164 kB
SReclaimable: 5872 kB
SUnreclaim: 19292 kB
KernelStack: 1040 kB
PageTables: 4028 kB
NFS_Unstable: 0 kB
Bounce: 0 kB
WritebackTmp: 0 kB
CommitLimit: 250416 kB

....

/proc/modules
Which kernel modules are loaded at the moment.

[root@devops ~]# cat /proc/modules
ipv6 322541 40 - Live 0xffffffffa0112000
xenfs 6087 1 - Live 0xffffffffa010b000
dm_mod 81692 0 - Live 0xffffffffa00eb000
xen_netfront 18905 0 - Live 0xffffffffa00da000
i2c_piix4 12608 0 - Live 0xffffffffa00d1000
i2c_core 31276 1 i2c_piix4, Live 0xffffffffa00c1000
sg 30124 0 - Live 0xffffffffa00b2000
ext3 240636 2 - Live 0xffffffffa0064000
jbd 80433 1 ext3, Live 0xffffffffa0045000
mbcache 8144 1 ext3, Live 0xffffffffa003d000
sr_mod 16228 0 - Live 0xffffffffa0033000
cdrom 39803 1 sr_mod, Live 0xffffffffa0022000

/proc/net
Status information about network protocols.

/proc/self
A symbolic link to the process directory of the program that is looking at /proc. When two processes look at /proc, they get different links. This is mainly a convenience to make it easier for programs to get at their process directory.

/proc/stat
Various statistics about the system, such as the number o

/proc/uptime
The time the system has been up.

/proc/version
The kernel version.
```

Comment: thanks but I am aware of these. But is there a way, any header file which can help me get this info from my kernel module so that I can do some processing on that info.

Comment: you can use /sbin/modinfo, for example, /sbin/modinfo ide-cd floppy

Comment: I think anubhav wants a C function that gets the information, not a command line program

Comment: Yes @spiffman I want to know if any header file provides functions to extract info about contents of proc folder.

Comment: Information under /proc is gathered in many different structures in the kernel. Thus, if you have run your code on kernel level, you have access to certain structures. Why do you need /proc at all there?

Comment: Just in case, more information in `man proc`.